# Add XSS validations/ sanitize script tags in Java

Tags: java, xss

I have an API written in Java where I am doing POST call but the malicious content is being sent to the API. Ideally, to prevent XSS attack, the API should not accept such data or at least sanitize it before storing/responding to it.

```
{"first_name":"<script>alert(document.cookie);</script>","last_name":"
<script>alert(document.cookie);</script>"}
```

I want to add XSS validations/ sanitize script tags in Java to prevent the content from XSS attack. Can anyone suggest the best way to prevent XSS attack in Java? Is there a way to encode and decode the HTML tags shown above?

After going through the different documentation, I found that [owasp-java-encoder](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-java-encoder) can be used to encode HTML content and this function can be used to encode HTML Content Context.

> <%= Encode.forHtmlContent(UNTRUSTED)
>   %>

I am looking for something which allows me to encode the HTML content while storing data and decode it while displaying it.

Comment: _"at least sanitize it *before* storing/responding to it"_ -- I personally _never_ do this. I don't block content, I don't sanitize content _before_ storing it in the database (because I have always run into the requirement that I have to store _*exactly*_ what the user typed) -- instead, you can sanitize on _output_ ... when you read from the DB and are sending it to some client, _then_ sanitize it. That also makes more sense, because _how_ you sanitize something depends on what the data is used for. Safety in a PDF is different than safety on a web page, or in JSON.

Comment: @StephenP Sanitizing before storing is important to prevent persisted XSS vulnerability (which is more dangerous than reflected version).

Comment: @java-addict301 - flatly, no it isn't. Did you read my entire previous comment? You need to sanitize before you _**use**_ what is stored for its intended purpose. If you receive `<script>...</script>` it is perfectly safe to store that. If you're then going to send that to a web page _then_ you need to sanitize it. But what if you're _**also**_ going to output that to a PDF? I don't want it to appear as `&lt;script&gt; ...` so it _should **not**_ be sanitized -- but _too late!_ you've already stored the sanitized version, which can't be safely reversed.

Comment: We are being required to do exactly what @java-addict301 is saying by our security people.  We would NEVER want to deliberately persist an attack vector into the database.  We have no requirement to allow garbage in exactly as typed.  That seems like that would be more of an exception case than the rule.

Comment: @StephenP Storing potentially malicious HTML to be both displayed in a browser and used for something else seems like a bad design practice to me.  Defense-in-depth approach would suggest sanitizing anything stored (as well as when it's retrieved) if its purpose is to be displayed in a browser.  It would be far too easy for malicious HTML to show up in a web browser if it's just sitting in your database for that purpose.

Comment: @java-addict301 I work on a web application where I need to store _exactly_ what the user entered so it can be redisplayed & also output to a PDF or Word file. Transforming something like `<tag>` into `&lt;tag>` before it is stored makes it indistinguishable from having typed `&lt;tag>` unless you also escape `&`, and then you get into a sanitization rabbit hole. Also `<tag>` isn't dangerous for a PDF. Sanitizing on the way _in_ to the database means I can never be sure what the user _really_ **actually** typed, and knowing that is a hard requirement for my application.

Comment: @StephenP in this case, I would sanitize the input client side also (unless you have a good case for allowing users to enter code into your input fields, but usually a rich text editor would suffice in this case).  This is just my opinion for how to handle such a requirement and is how many forums handle it for example.

Comment: @StephenP I would notify the client of invalid input also on the field if this was a UX concern.

Answer (score 1):

As Stephen P mentions, you should generally be encoding data on output.  You want to do this on output to ensure you're using the correct encoding for the output, and to prevent double encoding.  The OWASP encoders are a good choice for this.  See the [OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) for details on when to use various encoders.

You want to validate/sanitize on input as much as possible, using white list validation if possible.  But for free form text you won't, and shouldn't, do XSS encoding at this point.